# How to create a composite caption with node id using Neo4j Grass style file?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to display a custom caption on Neo4j nodes, this custom caption would be the id of the node `<id>` concatenated to a string.

Here is an extract from my GRASS file :

```
node.Company {
    color: #96e7bf;
    border-color: #96e7bf
    diameter: 65px;
    caption: 'Company';
}
```

If i set `caption = '<id>'`, the node displays the id of the node.
If i set `caption: 'Company'`, the node displays Company.
Buf if i set `caption: '<id> Company'`, the id is not displayed, i tried many syntaxes. I still can display composition caption like `'caption: 'Company {name} {city}'`, the issue is occuring with the `<id>` only!

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Ema

Comment: Not sure if it would be acceptable to you, but you could side-step this issue by giving `Company` nodes a very distinctive color (and using just `<id>` as the caption).

Comment: @cybersam thanks for answering, i tried this but we have so many nodes that the very distinctive color is unfortunately not enough !

Comment: The id of the node is not a robust solution. Why not have a property of the Company node such as company_id?